# $\sqrt {-6}$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt {-6}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $\sqrt{-6}|(a+b\sqrt{-6})(c+d\sqrt{-6})$. I need to show that $\sqrt{-6}$ does not divide $(a+b\sqrt{-6})$ and does not divide $(c+d\sqrt{-6})$. I thought you might arrive at some contradiction by supposing  $\sqrt{-6}(x+y\sqrt{-6})=(a+b\sqrt{-6})(c+d\sqrt{-6})$. Equating coefficients, $x=ad+bc$ and $y=bd$. I did the same for $\sqrt{-6}(x'+y'\sqrt{-6})=(a+b\sqrt{-6})$ and $\sqrt{-6}(x''+y''\sqrt{-6})=(c+d\sqrt{-6})$, but I'm not getting anywhere. I'm not really sure where to go

Comment: Well, it isn't true, in general. You don't have to prove it for all $a,b,c,d$, just for one $a,b,c,d...$

Comment: There's an error in your approach here. $a$ is prime if, whenever $a|bc$, $a|b$ or $a|c$. That does not mean that, if $a$ is not prime, then $a|bc\Rightarrow$ $a$ doesn't divide $b$ and $a$ doesn't divide $c$ for ALL $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Also, $-6y = ac-6bd$, not $y=bd$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$6=2\cdot 3$ is divisible by $\sqrt{-6}$, but neither $2$ nor $3$ is divisible by $\sqrt{-6}$.

You only need one counter-example. It's not possible for all examples of $\sqrt{-6}\mid XY$ to have $\sqrt{-6}\not\mid X$ and $\sqrt{-6}\not\mid Y$, because you could just pick $X=\sqrt{-6}$.

Comment: Yes, I was mistakenly trying to prove that $\sqrt{-6}$ divides $z*w\implies\sqrt{-6}$ doesn't divide $z$ and doesn't divide $w$ for all $z,w\in\mathbb{Z}+{Z}\sqrt{-6}$. Thank you for clearing this up for me. :)